# How do I post to Twitter using Unity3D with Authorization INSTEAD of PIN?

Tags: c#, android, api, twitter, unity-game-engine

I have a game completely in JavaScript. It sucks because I have to alter my C# plugins by shoving them into my plugin folder, and activate the commands inside the C# script using JavaScript.

I have downloaded "Let's Tweet in Unity" from the Asset store, and it comes with 2 Scripts. One script Defines "Twitter" and all the functions it can represent. The other is "Demo" which basically activates the functions within the Twitter Class.

So I altered "Demo" to my liking. But in this "Demo" it seems to want me to go through this process of Requesting a Token from twitter, which takes me to their website which gives me a Pin Number, then I have to go back to my app, paste the pin number, then write whatever I want to write, and only then I can post it.

I was wondering what methods I need to take to change this to that one method that just allows "such and such app" to have authentication to your Twitter account.

Currently the only commands I have are

```
GetRequestToken

GetAccessToken

PostToTwitter
```

And here is the script below:

```
using Twitter;
using UnityEngine;

public class TwitterTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You need to register your game or application in Twitter to get cosumer key and secret.
    // Go to this page for registration: http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
    public string CONSUMER_KEY;
    public string CONSUMER_SECRET;

// You need to save access token and secret for later use.
// You can keep using them whenever you need to access the user's Twitter account. 
// They will be always valid until the user revokes the access to your application.
const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID           = "TwitterUserID";
const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME  = "TwitterUserScreenName";
const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN        = "TwitterUserToken";
const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET = "TwitterUserTokenSecret";

Twitter.RequestTokenResponse m_RequestTokenResponse;
Twitter.AccessTokenResponse m_AccessTokenResponse;

string m_PIN = "Please enter your PIN here.";
string m_Tweet = "Please enter your tweet here.";

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{
    LoadTwitterUserInfo();

}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
}

public void Post() {
    /*post
    StartCoroutine(API.PostTweet("This is a twitter api test.",
                                CONSUMER_KEY,
                                CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                m_AccessTokenResponse,
                                OnPostTweet));
                                */

    StartCoroutine(Twitter.API.PostTweet("This is a twitter api test.",
                                         CONSUMER_KEY,
                                         CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                         m_AccessTokenResponse,
                                         new Twitter.PostTweetCallback(this.OnPostTweet)));
}
public void GetAccessToken() {
    StartCoroutine(Twitter.API.GetAccessToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, m_RequestTokenResponse.Token, m_PIN,
                                              new Twitter.AccessTokenCallback(this.OnAccessTokenCallback)));
}
public void GetRequestToken() {
    StartCoroutine(Twitter.API.GetRequestToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                               new Twitter.RequestTokenCallback(this.OnRequestTokenCallback)));

}
private void LoadTwitterUserInfo()
{
    m_AccessTokenResponse = new AccessTokenResponse();

    m_AccessTokenResponse.UserId = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID);
    m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME);
    m_AccessTokenResponse.Token = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN);
    m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.Token) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.Token) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret))
    {
        string log = "LoadTwitterUserInfo - succeeded";
        log += "\n    UserId : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.UserId;
        log += "\n    ScreenName : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName;
        log += "\n    Token : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.Token;
        log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret;
        Debug.Log(log);
    }
}

private void OnRequestTokenCallback(bool success, RequestTokenResponse response)
{
    if (success)
    {
        string log = "OnRequestTokenCallback - succeeded";
        log += "\n    Token : " + response.Token;
        log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + response.TokenSecret;
        print(log);

        m_RequestTokenResponse = response;

        //API.OpenAuthorizationPage(response.Token);
        //GetAccessToken();
        //Post();
    }
    else
    {
        print("OnRequestTokenCallback - failed.");
    }
}

private void OnAccessTokenCallback(bool success, AccessTokenResponse response)
{
    if (success)
    {
        string log = "OnAccessTokenCallback - succeeded";
        log += "\n    UserId : " + response.UserId;
        log += "\n    ScreenName : " + response.ScreenName;
        log += "\n    Token : " + response.Token;
        log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + response.TokenSecret;
        print(log);

        m_AccessTokenResponse = response;

        PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID, response.UserId);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME, response.ScreenName);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN, response.Token);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET, response.TokenSecret);

        //Post();
    }
    else
    {
        print("OnAccessTokenCallback - failed.");
    }
}

private void OnPostTweet(bool success)
{
    print("OnPostTweet - " + (success ? "succedded." : "failed."));
}
}
```

Comment: "unityscript" is deprecated, you must change to c# (fortunately it is easier)

Comment: The whole game is done. Like done done. In Javascript. I even have plugins of C# in it already. How do you expect me to rewrite my whole game to add one social feature?

Comment: "unityscript" is deprecated, you must change to c#.  (Fortunately it is easier.)